# Is Medea not the root of media?

Tags: etymology

Google definitions states that media has it roots in: late 19th century: shortening of modern Latin tunica (or membrana ) media ‘middle sheath (or layer)’.

This really did not make much sense to me, so I kept looking...

Than I found Medea, of ancient Greek mythology, Medea (/mɪˈdiːə/; Ancient Greek: Μήδεια, Mēdeia means "planner / schemer") is the daughter of King Aeëtes of Colchis...[Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medea)

From this I could construct media as Med-ia, works or articles of or like Medea..., and that seemed to make much more sense to me.

I wanted to see if that was a possibility, or if I'm simply getting "creative" with it.

Comment: What makes media "like Medea"? She was most famous for doing witchcraft and murdering her children (depending on the author), neither of which has much to do with methods of communication.

Comment: well apparently, there is a link to planner / schemer... -- yeah, as for the methods of communication angle -- I think we are clear on that now -- tks

Comment: Just remember: Google is not a real dictionary. It's an aggregate of information, and it shows you things based on AI, which means it's very often wrong. Try [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/media#etymonline_v_12509) for a more quick yet accurate online look-up tool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *media* that is shortened from *tunica media* is [the middle layer of the wall of a blood vessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunica_media). *Tunica media* literally means *middle tunic*, though *tunica* was metaphorically extended to mean 'membrane'.

It's not the same as the in origin plural neuter noun *media* you're thinking of, which is shortened from *communications media*, where *medium* (the singular) means 'means'. The Latin noun *medium* originally also meant 'middle', as it's just a nominal use of the adjective, but that's not the meaning in which it was borrowed in this context.

There's no great mystery in these etymologies. Medea is obviously unrelated.

Comment: thanks, also I found this https://etymologeek.com/lat/medium

Comment: [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/medium) also gives a good sense of the relationships between the different meanings of *medium*: intervening substance, channel of communications, thing in painting that carries the pigment, etc.